# Add successive rows in Pandas if they match on some columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following one:

```
ID  URL     seconds
1   Email       9
1   Email       3
1   App         5
1   App         9
1   Faceboook   50
1   Faceboook   7
1   Faceboook   39
1   Faceboook   10
1   Email       39
1   Email       5
1   Email       57
1   Faceboook   7
1   Faceboook   32
1   Faceboook   3
2   App         11
2   App         10
2   Email       56
2   Faceboook   9
2   Faceboook   46
2   Faceboook   16
2   Email       21
```

I want to sum the 'seconds' column for successive views of the same URL by the same ID. That's the result I'm looking for:

```
ID  URL     seconds
1   Email       12
1   App         14
1   Faceboook   106
1   Email       101
1   Faceboook   42
2   App         21
2   Email       56
2   Faceboook   71
2   Email       21
```

`df.groupBy(['ID', 'URL']).sum()` would not work in this case as it would sum all cases of the same URL for the same ID, not only the successive ones.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Series` created by compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) column `URL` and shifted, last use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with `boolean mask`:

```
print ((df.URL.ne(df.URL.shift())).cumsum())
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     4
9     4
10    4
11    5
12    5
13    5
14    6
15    6
16    7
17    8
18    8
19    8
20    9
Name: URL, dtype: int32
```

```
print (df['seconds'].groupby([(df.URL.ne(df.URL.shift())).cumsum(), df.ID, df.URL]).sum())

URL  ID  URL      
1    1   Email         12
2    1   App           14
3    1   Faceboook    106
4    1   Email        101
5    1   Faceboook     42
6    2   App           21
7    2   Email         56
8    2   Faceboook     71
9    2   Email         21
Name: seconds, dtype: int64

print (df['seconds'].groupby([(df.URL.ne(df.URL.shift())).cumsum(), df.ID, df.URL])
                    .sum()
                    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                    .reset_index())

   ID        URL  seconds
0   1      Email       12
1   1        App       14
2   1  Faceboook      106
3   1      Email      101
4   1  Faceboook       42
5   2        App       21
6   2      Email       56
7   2  Faceboook       71
8   2      Email       21
```

Comment: I think you also need to handle the case of `1 Facebook; 2 Facebook`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I dont understand, can you explain more?

Comment: Never mind I think your code actually does handle that case.  Nice one.